# Why won't image_tag show an image on site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image

I'm working in Cloud 9, trying to display an image using the `image_tag` and I'm getting this placeholder symbol that Chrome can't find my image. I uploaded the image from my computer to `assets/images/logos/light_blue.png`.

I don't understand why the image doesn't show up. The code I use is:

```
<%= image_tag ("light_blue.png") %>
```

[A screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEAY0.png)

[The result in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyFqw.png)

The same thing happens with a JPG.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, and "[mcve]". We need to see the minimum code that demonstrates the problem _in the question itself_. Links to code will rot and break, resulting in a question that doesn't make sense to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Rails is searching for your image in the directory `./assets` and not in `./assets/images/logos/light_blue.png`.

If you change the path, it will work, if the image is in that folder.

```
<%= image_tag ('images/logos/light_blue.png') %>
```

The [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-image_path) gives you a few more examples.

Comment: I appreciate your time in responding and the link!  I did try what you recommended and I got the same result.  However, I just deleted my logos folder and uploaded the image in: assets/images.  After I did that, it worked.

Comment: I am curious however, why did it not work before?  I created a logo's folder by right clicking and creating a new folder under the images folder just to keep things organized...any ideas??  I just find it odd.